# Expressing a boolean expression as a finite state machine

Tags: boolean, fsm

Is it possible to express a boolean expression as a finite state machine such that the FSM accepts an input that matches the boolean expression ?

Is it possible to merge multiple such FSMs, and upon acceptation, to know which original FSM did match ?

Background: I'm trying to evaluate a lot of boolean expressions at once. I'm thinking that with the correct representation, maybe a DFA could do that super efficiently (i.e. better than O(n) with n = number of expressions).

Comment: It depends.  When you say "boolean expression", what kind of predicate are you speaking of ?  What are your allowed boolean operations and "input values"/"atoms" ?

Comment: Boolean expressions with AND/OR/NOT. Input is a list of unordered boolean variables.

Comment: So you use propositional logic.  I don't know how to do better than O(n), you still need to evaluate every proposition.  (if n is the length of the boolean list, I misunderstood, and I don't see either how to perform better than O(n) when a proposition is x1 AND x2 AND ... AND xn)  What you can do, is to improve the average case by converting to a conjunctive normal form, then reusing computation you already did.  However I fail to see how that would be faster than simple boolean arithmetic.  Can you give the order of magnitude of "a lot".  How many expressions and input list per expression ?

Comment: A regular expression like `bar|baz` can be easily expressed as a NFA and converted to a DFA. The DFA will be evaluated once for the two alternations, and this is faster than evaluating both separately. Maybe it's possible with boolean expressions too. The order of magnitude is 1000 expressions with 20 terms each.

Comment: The point of the DFA in a regex is to avoid backtracking while matching.  The DFA itself is computed once, but each time you feed it a character string, you still need to traverse the DFA.  A propositional expression is much more simple and it's already deterministic, there is no "deterministic" version to compute.

Comment: It becomes non-deterministic when you have more than one expression: `a`, `a AND b`. After matching `a`, you can either accept the first expression, or continue matching the second one.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you meant.  You use the disjunctive normal form, split the conjunctive sub-expressions, and want to build an automaton that accept all those sub-expressions.  That's a nice idea.  You could definitively get away with a decision tree.  Be sure it's worth to build it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but I did find myself in similar situations and I think there are *some* cases where an FSM might offer some help in complex boolean logic.

One example I outlined in a [blog post of mine](https://dev.to/sukima/state-machines-work-for-logic-too-494p) where I described the use of a state machine while walking (looping) through the tokens of a simple string.

The advantage in this case was that instead of each token in the parsing process having a dedicated boolean flag which other paths in the syntax tree would need to guard against I could just feed each token as an event to the FSM and let the machine fall into different states. I used Statechart actions to build up little op-codes while it was processing and then finally based on the final state either abort or go on to compiling the generated op-codes.

You will have to read the article to gain a context of what I said above. But the gist of it is that in some cases a series of booleans could be converted to event names and passed to an FSM for processing. In another example I had to choose which UI state I needed to render based on a set of overwhelming boolean logic.

Because some flags took precedence over others the resulting logic tree looked like this:

Figure 1 — example UML activity diagram

[image: UML Activity diagram]

Which resulted in code that looked a bit like this:

Figure 2 — complex boolean logic code

```
let presenterFlags = {
  showSpecialTypeTab: model.type === 'special',
  showDefaultWarning: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault && !settings.enforced),
  showDefaultInBrokenStateWarning: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault && settings.enforce),
  disableSaveButton: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault && !settings.enforce) || !model.canWrite,
  disableCancelButton: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault && !settings.enforce) || !model.canWrite,
  disableDeleteButton: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault) || !model.canWrite,
  disableEnforcementToggle: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault && !settings.enforced) || !model.canWrite,
  disableAnotherToggle: (model.type === 'special' && model.isDefault) || !model.canWrite,
};
```

Which to me was too much for my brain to bear. So I leaned on the use of an FSM which resulted in a State diagram like:

Figure 3 — example UML State diagram

[image: UML State diagram]

Using [XState](https://xstate.js.org) the code might have looked like this:

Figure 4 — example XState machine

```
let booleanMachine = Machine({
  id: 'ExamplePresentationFlags',
  strict: true,
  initial: 'conditional',
  context: {},
  states: {
    conditional: {
      on: {
        'EVALUATE': [
          { target: 'SpecialExample', cond: 'isSpecialExample' },
          { target: 'GenaricExample' },
        ],
      },
    },
    GenaricExample: {
      initial: 'conditional',
      states: {
        conditional: {
          on: {
            '': [
              { target: 'ReadOnly', cond: 'canNotWrite' },
              { target: 'Default', cond: 'isDefault' },
              { target: 'Writable' },
            ],
          },
        },
        Writable: {},
        Default: {},
        ReadOnly: {
          meta: {
            disableSaveButton: true,
            disableCancelButton: true,
            disableDeleteButton: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    SpecialExample: {
      initial: 'conditional',
      meta: { showSpecialTypeTab: true },
      states: {
        conditional: {
          on: {
            '': [
              { target: 'ReadOnly', cond: 'canNotWrite' },
              { target: 'Default', cond: 'isDefault' },
              { target: 'Writable' },
            ],
          },
        },
        Writable: {},
        ReadOnly: {
          meta: {
            disableSaveButton: true,
            disableCancelButton: true,
            disableDeleteButton: true,
            disableAnotherToggle: true,
          },
        },
        Default: {
          initial: 'conditional',
          states: {
            conditional: {
              on: {
                '': [
                  { target: 'Enforced', cond: 'isEnforced' },
                  { target: 'Unenforced' },
                ],
              },
            },
            Unenforced: {
              meta: {
                exampleWarning: 'default-read-only',
                disableSaveButton: true,
                disableCancelButton: true,
                disableDeleteButton: true,
                disableAnotherToggle: true,
              },
            },
            Enforced: {
              meta: {
                exampleWarning: 'special-default-broken-enforce-state',
                disableSaveButton: false,
                disableCancelButton: false,
                disableDeleteButton: true,
                disableAnotherToggle: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}, {
  guards: {
    isSpecialExample: (ctx) => ctx.exampleType === 'special',
    canNotWrite: (ctx) => !ctx.canWrite,
    isEnforced: (ctx) => ctx.isEnforced,
    isDefault: (ctx) => ctx.isDefault,
    isNotDefault: (ctx) => !ctx.isDefault,
  },
});
```

With a reducer like function:

Figure 5 — example XState reducer function

```
function presentorFlags({ canWrite, model, settings }) {
  let machine = booleanMachine.withContext({
    canWrite,
    exampleType: model.type,
    isEnforced: settings.enforced,
    isDefault: model.isDefault,
  });
  let { meta } = machine.transition(machine.initialState, 'EVALUATE');
  return Object.keys(meta)
    .reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, ...meta[key] }), {});
}
```

Understand that I agree this example is unconventional and also bigger. It did provide me the ability to understand the logic especially with the visualization tools at hand (i.e. Figure 3). At the time it allowed me to conceptualize all the edge case states and not have to worry about what each state of the UI meant as far as view code was concerned. Instead I could focus on the states themselves and what logic would get the machine into that state. Then I gave the reducer the actual boolean values and let the machine do the work. What I get back is just a set of UI flags that is easy to place in my template.

Again, maybe this is not better or maybe it is. The point is that it **is possible** to use a state machine to express boolean logic.